# Is there a way to get the names/ ID's of all sheets within a spreadsheet?

Tags: swift, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to know either all sheets name or ID number in a specific spreadsheet, but I cannot find anything that will help me. There are many people who have done this in other languages other than swift, but swift is unique in the way it uses and handles the google sheets API. I do not even know how to get started. Is there anything anyone has that can help?

I don't know where to start, and I am having a lot of trouble with this. I want to be able to use a dropdown menu (from iOSDropDown) to select one of the existing sheets, but I need a way to find the sheets name or ID. People have done it in JavaScript, but there is literally almost no support for swift on the internet. I have already been through the sheets API's hundreds of times, and I have searched through stack overflow and other places as well.

I do not have any results.

Comment: You must visit the [Sheets API documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts) if you are not sure where to start with. Also, you can check the [swift documentation](https://swift.org/documentation/#the-swift-programming-language) on how you can integrate API's using this language. These [swift cheat sheet from github](https://github.com/jugend/swift-cheat-sheet) could also help you with the tricks.

Comment: I have already been through every single google API sheet, everything on stack overflow and GitHub. I have an app that does what I need it to do except for this one thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the names, I ended up having a number on the sheet that I add one to every time and I put the name of that sheet right below the last sheet.